# How to do XML Parsing on GENIA corpus in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, nlp, elementtree

I have the following pattern of XML that I want to parse to get all the full sentences in one list and all the text between  tag in one list

```
<article>
<articleinfo>
<bibliomisc>MEDLINE:95369245</bibliomisc>
</articleinfo>
<title>
<sentence><cons lex="IL-2_gene_expression" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="IL-2_gene" sem="G#DNA_domain_or_region">IL-2 gene</cons> expression</cons> and <cons lex="NF-kappa_B_activation" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="NF-kappa_B" sem="G#protein_molecule">NF-kappa B</cons> activation</cons> through <cons lex="CD28" sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons> requires reactive oxygen production by <cons lex="5-lipoxygenase" sem="G#protein_molecule">5-lipoxygenase</cons>.</sentence>
</title>
<abstract>
<sentence>Activation of the <cons lex="CD28_surface_receptor" sem="G#protein_family_or_group"><cons lex="CD28" sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons> surface receptor</cons> provides a major costimulatory signal for <cons lex="T_cell_activation" sem="G#other_name">T cell activation</cons> resulting in enhanced production of <cons lex="interleukin-2" sem="G#protein_molecule">interleukin-2</cons> (<cons lex="IL-2" sem="G#protein_molecule">IL-2</cons>) and <cons lex="cell_proliferation" sem="G#other_name">cell proliferation</cons>.</sentence>
<sentence>In <cons lex="primary_T_lymphocyte" sem="G#cell_type">primary T lymphocytes</cons> we show that <cons lex="CD28" sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons> ligation leads to the rapid intracellular formation of <cons lex="reactive_oxygen_intermediate" sem="G#inorganic">reactive oxygen intermediates</cons> (<cons lex="ROI" sem="G#inorganic">ROIs</cons>) which are required for <cons lex="CD28-mediated_activation" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="CD28" sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>-mediated activation</cons> of the <cons lex="NF-kappa_B" sem="G#protein_molecule">NF-kappa B</cons>/<cons lex="CD28-responsive_complex" sem="G#protein_complex"><cons lex="CD28" sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>-responsive complex</cons> and <cons lex="IL-2_expression" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="IL-2" sem="G#protein_molecule">IL-2</cons> expression</cons>.</sentence>
<sentence>Delineation of the <cons lex="CD28_signaling_cascade" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="CD28" sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons> signaling cascade</cons> was found to involve <cons lex="protein_tyrosine_kinase_activity" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="protein_tyrosine_kinase" sem="G#protein_family_or_group">protein tyrosine kinase</cons> activity</cons>, followed by the activation of <cons lex="phospholipase_A2" sem="G#protein_molecule">phospholipase A2</cons> and <cons lex="5-lipoxygenase" sem="G#protein_molecule">5-lipoxygenase</cons>.</sentence>
<sentence>Our data suggest that <cons lex="lipoxygenase_metabolite" sem="G#protein_family_or_group"><cons lex="lipoxygenase" sem="G#protein_molecule">lipoxygenase</cons> metabolites</cons> activate <cons lex="ROI_formation" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="ROI" sem="G#inorganic">ROI</cons> formation</cons> which then induce <cons lex="IL-2" sem="G#protein_molecule">IL-2</cons> expression via <cons lex="NF-kappa_B_activation" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="NF-kappa_B" sem="G#protein_molecule">NF-kappa B</cons> activation</cons>.</sentence>
<sentence>These findings should be useful for <cons lex="therapeutic_strategies" sem="G#other_name">therapeutic strategies</cons> and the development of <cons lex="immunosuppressants" sem="G#other_name">immunosuppressants</cons> targeting the <cons lex="CD28_costimulatory_pathway" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="CD28" sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons> costimulatory pathway</cons>.</sentence>
</abstract>
</article>
</set>
```

I tried doing something like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET



root = ET.parse("test.xml").getroot()

sent= [elem.text for elem in root.iter('sentence')]
print(sent)
terms =  [elem.text for elem in root.iter('cons')]

print(terms)
```

but this gives the following output.

```
[None, 'Activation of the ', 'In ', 'Delineation of the ', 'Our data suggest that ', 'These findings should be useful for ']
[None, 'IL-2 gene', None, 'NF-kappa B', 'CD28', '5-lipoxygenase', None, 'CD28', 'T cell activation', 'interleukin-2', 'IL-2', 'cell proliferation', 'primary T lymphocytes', 'CD28', 'reactive oxygen intermediates', 'ROIs', None, 'CD28', 'NF-kappa B', None, 'CD28', None, 'IL-2', None, 'CD28', None, 'protein tyrosine kinase', 'phospholipase A2', '5-lipoxygenase', None, 'lipoxygenase', None, 'ROI', 'IL-2', None, 'NF-kappa B', 'therapeutic strategies', 'immunosuppressants', None, 'CD28']
```

I want an output closer to the following

```
['IL-2 gene expression and NF-kappa B activation through CD28 requires oxygen production by 5-lipoxygenase', ...]
['IL-2 gene','NF-kappa B', 'CD28', '5-lipoxygenase',...]
```

The term list seems fine in my output but how do I get full sentences in my `sent` list instead of the broken sentences I am currently getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part is that some of the text in your xml isn't .text; it's .tail.

For the sentences it's easy enough to do something like:

```py
sent = [''.join(elem.itertext()) for elem in root.iter('sentence')]
```

For the terms (cons) it's a little different because it looks like you're wanting to ignore the text of `cons` elements that have a child `cons`. (Really you don't want the .text of the child `cons`.)

In that case just grab the .text if it's not None...

```py
terms = [elem.text for elem in tree.iter('cons') if elem.text]
```

Full example...

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')

sent = [''.join(elem.itertext()) for elem in tree.iter('sentence')]
print(sent)

terms = [elem.text for elem in tree.iter('cons') if elem.text]
print(terms)
```

prints...

```py
['IL-2 gene expression and NF-kappa B activation through CD28 requires reactive oxygen production by 5-lipoxygenase.', 'Activation of the CD28 surface receptor provides a major costimulatory signal for T cell activation resulting in enhanced production of interleukin-2 (IL-2) and cell proliferation.', 'In primary T lymphocytes we show that CD28 ligation leads to the rapid intracellular formation of reactive oxygen intermediates (ROIs) which are required for CD28-mediated activation of the NF-kappa B/CD28-responsive complex and IL-2 expression.', 'Delineation of the CD28 signaling cascade was found to involve protein tyrosine kinase activity, followed by the activation of phospholipase A2 and 5-lipoxygenase.', 'Our data suggest that lipoxygenase metabolites activate ROI formation which then induce IL-2 expression via NF-kappa B activation.', 'These findings should be useful for therapeutic strategies and the development of immunosuppressants targeting the CD28 costimulatory pathway.']
['IL-2 gene', 'NF-kappa B', 'CD28', '5-lipoxygenase', 'CD28', 'T cell activation', 'interleukin-2', 'IL-2', 'cell proliferation', 'primary T lymphocytes', 'CD28', 'reactive oxygen intermediates', 'ROIs', 'CD28', 'NF-kappa B', 'CD28', 'IL-2', 'CD28', 'protein tyrosine kinase', 'phospholipase A2', '5-lipoxygenase', 'lipoxygenase', 'ROI', 'IL-2', 'NF-kappa B', 'therapeutic strategies', 'immunosuppressants', 'CD28']
```

Note: `terms` will have duplicates. If you need to get rid of the duplicates there are a few different ways to do that. For example, use a set():

```py
terms = list(set(elem.text for elem in tree.iter('cons') if elem.text))
```